# jQuery: how to add buttons that can in turn add more buttons

Tags: jquery

I am writing a script that allows users to add friends on a form.  I need to be able to have them add a friend, click an add button button next to the input, add another friend, click the add button next to that input and so on.  I am trying to do that with jQuery, but am stuck.  I achieved this, but my script adds buttons like I want, but it adds inside the original button.  I know it is because I am using "this" in my script, but I can't get it working without this.  If my code is not the way to do this, I am open to other suggestions.  Here is my code, which is wrapped in document.ready higher up in the script:

```
$("button#add-friend").click(function (e) {
      $(this).trigger('addFriend');
});
$('#add-friend').on('addFriend', function() {
      $(this).append('<input type="text" value="Friend"><span id="add"><input type="button" id="add-friend" value="+"></span><br/>');
});
```

The HTML is:

```
<input type="text" value="Friend"><span id="add"><input type="button" id="add-friend" value="+"></span>
<div id="add-friend"></div>
```

By the way I am using jQuery 1.7, which has the new "on" syntax.  ".on('click', ... )" is the same as ".click(...)"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery's live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and attach an event handler based on a CSS class. This will allow you to create a generic event handler that will be fired even for dynamically created buttons.

You should use [jQuery's parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to navigate the DOM tree and insert the generated HTML in the desired location.

Also you're IDs aren't unique at the moment, so that will be causing some trouble, as you discovered. You're probably better off using class names, as IDs should be unique.

Comment: Live has been replaced by "on."  I tried that and the dynamically added buttons didn't work.

Comment: @shummel7845 it has not been replaced. `live` is still there, just it might be better to use `on`

Comment: My bad.  I should have said deprecated.

Comment: You're right, `live` has been deprecated. Principles remain largely the same though.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `<div id="add-friend"></div>` is **not** a button!

So it trumps the other DOM element that you have with the same id. make you IDs unique!

Here is one that works: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/nsJ3E/

Comment: @shummel7845 thats bc ur not using `live` (or `on`) for the click.